# How to print a specific element of a list in python by searching if a word is in that element?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list, each element is a string with a name and a location.
I'm trying to print all the strings in the list which contain a specific name or location.

I can print a specific string using the index, and I can check if a string of the list contain a specific keyword (like a location name) but I don't know how to print the results. Thanks for any help, I'm new to python.

```
list = open("list.txt", "r")
keyword = input("instert keyword: ")

for element in list.readlines():
  print(element)
list.close()
#this print out every element in the list
#how can I print an element which contains a specific keyword?
```

Comment: your question sentence has the relevant clues. `"**if** a word is **in** that element"`. You may want to search up those keywords in a python tutorial and familiarize yourself with how you can use them here.

Comment: Unrelated: your variable `list` is better named as `file` since that's what the `open()` function returns—a file handler, not a list. (Also using `list` as a variable name will shadow the built-in type.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `in` keyword, so during the loop:

```
for element in my_list.readlines():
  if 'target_word' in element:
      print(element)
```

That should work.

Comment: Do not use the name of a built-in (list) for a variable.

Comment: I was simply using OP's code as an example. I have edited it out @gboffi.